# how to configure route 53 to maintain domain name in browser for URL redirect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I have a static website that is hosted in an AWS S3 bucket. To access this website in the browser I use the endpoint like: my-website-bucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

I have then registered a domain (e.g. my-domain.com) in Route 53 and created 2 ALIAS records (my-domain.com, www.my-domain.com) that both use an alias target to my-website-bucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

I have also set up S3 buckets for both my-domain.com and www.my-domain.com and configured them per the instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

When I open the domain in the browser (http://my-domain.com, http://www.my-domain.com), my website correctly loads, but the URL in the browser changes from my domain names to the S3 bucket name, which is undesired as I want my domain name to be listed in the browser.

Edit1:

Record Set:

Type: A

Name: my-domain.com.

Alias: Yes

Alias hosted zone ID: xxxxxxxx

Alias target: s3-website-us-east1.amazonaws.com.

Evaluate target health: No

TTL: -

Routing policy (simple): -

Associated health check ID: -

Value: -

Edit2:

```
C:\Users\Me>curl -v my-domain.com
* Rebuilt URL to: my-domain.com/
*   Trying 12.211.9.128...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my-domain.com (12.211.9.128) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: my-domain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< x-amz-id-2: wdbVEZergC3Jw+Q/lQx0bdBXMyWxNNx+3m29ymwDksbCldjxP/QA6X0K1YjBxjJhIwbpecmVHqw=
< x-amz-request-id: 0D89EEC2x6D97555
< Date: Fri, 06 Dec 2019 10:06:23 GMT
< Location: http://my-website-folder.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: AmazonS3
<
* Connection #0 to host my-domain.com left intact

C:\Users\Me>
```

[image: Route 53]

Question: how to configure Route 53 and/or S3 to make the domain stay as the URL in the browser, and not switch to the S3 bucket URL?

Edit3:

S3 static website hosting config for my 3 buckets (2 buckets to map to the domain, and one that contains the actual website)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 things:

1. **Bucket name** must **same** with domain name.
2. Use `s3-website-REGION-NAME.amazonaws.com.` as Alias value. (when bucket name and domain name are same, you will selectable from DropDownList

Update:

Because you select redirect from both buckets to my-website-folder bucket => aws will redirect (301) to that bucket endpoint.

Remember that redirect is not CName. I suggest to clone my-website-folder to your domain bucket.

Best solution is using cloudfont front your endpoint

Comment: That’s what I’ve done. The redirect is working correctly but the URL in the browser is changed from my domain (my-domain.com) to my s3 bucket endpoint. While this allows people to get to my website by using my domain, the name of the domain doesn’t stay in the browser which doesn’t look great. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @AHL Can you share the capture of your Route53 alias?

Comment: Done - for one of the alias records. The other one is identical, just for www.my-domain.com

Comment: added further details.

Comment: I think you route53 is good, problem maybe from s3. Please share more on s3, like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnXrI.png

Comment: Because you select redirect from both buckets to my-website-folder bucket => aws will redirect (301) to that bucket endpoint. Remember that redirect is not CName. I suggest to clone my-website-folder to your domain bucket. Best solution is using cloudfont front your endpoint

Comment: Thanks - I will try both solutions tomorrow !